# pyodbc.drivers() = []?

Tags: pyodbc

i have a python project running with pyodbc, where I connect with a IBM i server.

When I want to connect with

```
    connection = pyodbc.connect(
        DRIVER='{iSeries Access ODBC Driver}',
        SYSTEM='192.111.111.111',
        UID='LUKESKYWALKER',
        PWD='TATOOINE123')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
```

I get

```
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Der Datenquellenname wurde nicht gefunden, und es wurde kein Standardtreiber angegeben (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Also when I want to try

```
print(pyodbc.drivers())
```

I get a empty list - I have tried to uninstall pyodbc and reinstall with Python packages in pycharm, but the error is still there

Comment: Installing pyodbc does not install any ODBC drivers. The required driver for your target database must be installed separately.

Comment: @GordThompson: i know, i have IBM i Access installed - in ODBC setup menu in Windows, I have them all listed.
And, as far as I know, installing e.g Office is adding Excel Driver, but this is also not there listed.

Comment: Perhaps you are running 32-bit Python and it is unable to see 64-bit drivers (or vice-versa). Or are you running Python under WSL?